# Child_process with impersonation?

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, authentication, child-process

I'm trying to create a virtual bash in my node script that executes commands from within another user context.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var terminal = spawn('bash', [], { uid: 1001 });

terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

terminal.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

terminal.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

terminal.stdin.write('echo Hello $USER');
terminal.stdin.end();
```

After executing this as root the output allways is

```
Hello root
```

As you can see in my example I've passed a user id to the spawn, but this doesn't effect anything.

My desired output is (assumed uid 1001's username is 'foobar'):

```
Hello foobar
```

Is there a way to do this in node or even a "fake" where I can start a `bash` process with given user credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Your `bash` instance has in fact the permission of your `foobar` user, and the code you wrote is correct.

You can confirm this behavior if you run the following command, instead of bash:

```js
terminal       = spawn('id', ['-a'], { uid: 1001 });
```

which should output this:

```
stdout: uid=1001(foobar)
```

Which you can compare to a standard child spawn, without the `uid` parameter:

```js
terminal       = spawn('id', ['-a']);
```

which outputs:

```bash
stdout: uid=0(root)
```

---

Here is the relevant explanation, according to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/setuid-bit-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-bash):

> bash detects that it has been started SUID root (UID!=EUID) and uses
>   its root power to throw this power away, resetting EUID to UID.

which means that when `bash` starts, it's SUID is root, and then it sets its `USER` variable to `root`. Only **after** that does it uses `setuid`.